# How to combine many single result queries into a single query with multiple results

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have currently have a table (post) with the following columns:

`id, stock_code, posted_at`

For a given stock code SC and time T1, I can retrieve the newest post after a certain time with something like

`SELECT * FROM post WHERE stock_code = SC AND time > T1 ORDER BY time asc LIMIT 1;` (not actually tested, but you get the gist)

However, I want to get that result for a set of multiple stocks (or even for every distinct stock code in the table). I could simply run this query multiple times, however that quickly becomes inefficient, and it would be best to combine into one SQL query, however I can't wrap my head around how to do that. I would like each row to be the newest post after a certain time for a given stock, and have one row for each stock. How do I go about doing this?

P.S. Using Postgres 9.4.8, and SqlAlchemy on the python side. Would be happy with just SQL, however if there is some SqlAlchemy magic to get to the same result that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (stock_code) p.*
FROM post p
WHERE p.stock_code = 'SC' AND p.time > T1
ORDER BY p.stock_code, time asc;
```

Obviously, with the `WHERE` clause, this will return one row.  You can remove the `p.stock_code = 'SC'` and get one row per `stock_code`.

Comment: perfect, that was a much simpler solution than I envisioned. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use `union` or `union all` to group results from may queries in one.